# Firebase authStateChanges method does not trigger from a screen that was pushed

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm new to flutter and was learning about Firebase Authentication using Email + Password verification. I have a simple UI with 3 screen: Login, Register and Home. After successfully registering or logging in, the home screen should be shown. The default screen to be shown if no user is currently signed in is Login screen. There is a button in login screen that pushes register screen using `Navigator.push()` when the user clicks on it. I have used a stream builder in the home parameter of the `MaterialApp` with the stream `FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges()`.

However `authStateChanges()` does not seem to get triggered when I use it from the register screen. Here's the code:

main.dart:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

import 'firebase_options.dart';
import 'screens/login.dart';
import 'screens/home.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Firebase Auth Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return HomeScreen(userEmail: snapshot.data!.email!);
          }
          return const LoginScreen();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

login function in login.dart:

```
  void loginPressed() async {
    final isValid = _formKey.currentState!.validate();
    if (isValid) {
      try {
        await _firebase.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: _emailController.text,
          password: _pswdController.text,
        );
      } on FirebaseAuthException catch (error) {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
          ..clearSnackBars()
          ..showSnackBar(
            SnackBar(
              content: Text(
                error.message ?? 'Login failed. Try again.',
              ),
            ),
          );
      }
    }
  }
```

register function in register.dart:

```
void registerPressed() async {
  FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
  final isValid = _formKey.currentState!.validate();
  if (isValid) {
    try {
      await _firebase.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
       email: _emailController.text,
       password: _pswdController.text,
     );
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (error) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
        ..clearSnackBars()
        ..showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(
            content: Text(
              error.message ?? 'Authentication failed. Try again.',
            ),
          ),
        );
    }
  }
}
```

The user is successfully registered as no error is thrown but the home screen won't show. What am I doing wrong?

Please let me know if any other info is required.

firebase_auth version: 4.7.2

firebase_core version: 2.15.0

I am running the code on simulator iPhone 14 Pro

UPDATE:

In `registerPressed()` I pushedReplacement after the user has been registered like so:

```
await _firebase
  .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: _emailController.text,
    password: _pswdController.text,
  )
  .then(
    (value) => Navigator.pushReplacement(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const MyApp()),
    ),
  );
```

It works as expected but is it the correct way?